# DIV of Social Icons Not Appearing On Wordpress Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, icons

I have a set of social media icons in the footer of my [website.](https://highereg.com)

The icons are inserted there via a Text widget; the code for the icons is as follows -

```
<div class="icon-benz-footer" style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center;">[social-media items_align="center"]</div>
```

For some reason, the icons won't appear on a mobile device. How do I rectify this?

Comment: You can get rid of float: center that does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked you website and the .site-footer-first-widget-area is hidden on mobile phones. The code for this is present in the main.css file.

If you want it to be always visible you can make the following changes to your main.css

```
/*=========================================================================
   3. Footer styles
 ======================================================*/

.site-footer-first-widget-area
{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

PS: your inline css in the opening post has a small flaw. There is no such thing as float: center;

Hope this answer helps!